# Authentication does not work

Tags: php, security, symfony

I have set a secured area using http_basic . I can see the box with username and password fields but even if I put correct information I get the box again and again as if I used wrong ones.
My security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/fournisseur, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                admin: { password: kitten, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
```

PS: I am using an SSL certificate overall my web site.

Comment: Does your server work under apache+fastcgi ?

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using? There's a slight change between 2.0 and 2.1 YML structure (the extra `memory` under `in_memory`)

Comment: Seems to be a loop due to you /login is under firewall too.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the security options can be a daunting task. To get you started, make sure to check the most common pitfalls with configuring security in Symfony2: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#book-security-common-pitfalls

Hope this gives you a little push in the right direction.